# How to narrow down results in Django QuerySets?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
|---------------------------------------|
|                                       |
|   user-1 | blogpost-2 |  date_added   |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|-------------- two-months -------------|
|                                       |
|   user-1 | blogpost-1 |  date_added   |
|                                       |
|   user-2 | blogpost-1 |  date_added   |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

The compartment above "two-months" separator shows posts that were posted within the last two months. The bottom one shows posts that are more that two months old. Its just a logical separation that I have created to explain my question. I want to find all the users who have not made any blog post since the last two months. So the ideal result for this would be user-2. I was trying to do something like this in Django but its wrong I guess.

```
logs = Blogs.objects.exclude(
        date_added__gt=query_date
    ).values('user_id')
```

This would be evaluated to something like this:

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `blogs` WHERE NOT (`date_added` > 2014-04-17 08:34:04 )
```

which essentially is not what I want as it would return user-1 and user-2 both.

How am I supposed to solve this kind of problem using Django QuerySets?

***Note***: Blog and User models are not related to each other. The table is only used for archiving purposes.

Comment: Do you want to get only users or all blog posts of that users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from the `User` object and then [follow the reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships):

```
User.objects.exclude(blog__date_added__gt=query_date)
```

**Update:**

You updated your question to point out that `Blog` and `User` models are not related to each other. This is usually not a good idea, but you can work around the issue using [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

```
Blogs.objects.values('user_id').annotate(last_post=Max('date_added')).exclude(last_post__gt=query_date)
```

Note that the `values('user_id')` part is quite important here, because it [allows for grouping of all posts made by a given user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values).

Comment: This won't be able to resolve because it cannot find the keyword 'blog'. Reason being that there is no relationship between User and Blog models.

Comment: But there is a relationship between `Blog` and `User` model, isn't it?

Comment: Nopes. Unfortunately, there is none.

Comment: You mean there is a field for user id in the `Blog` model, but it's not marked as `ForeignKey` pointing to the `User` model? Frankly, that's nuts. If there is *any* way you can change this you really should. The whole idea of Django ORM is based on explicit relationships between models.

Comment: Yep thats the case and I know that is nuts. But its an archiving table so its fine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping by users and annotating the oldest date:

```
Blog.values('user_id'
   ).annotate(oldest=Max('date_added')
   ).exclude(oldest__gt=query_date)
   ).values('user_id')
```